# Concurrent Powershell jobs not running command

Tags: multithreading, powershell, concurrency, server

Hey guys first time poster long time reader, I'm having a bit of trouble with my script at the moment and was hoping some would check it out and point out where I've gone wrong, it is as follows:

```
$Servers = gc "C:\ServerList.txt"
 $SB = {
    Start-Process {cmd (C:\psexec.exe \\$Server -u username -p password cmd /c "echo.| powershell C:\Autolog.ps1")
       }
Foreach ($Server in $Servers) 
    {
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $SB
    }
```

Essentially what I'm trying to get this script to do is for Every server in "Serverslist.txt" Start a PSEXEC which then initiates an Powershell script on said server

What i'm seeing is that the jobs start but my psexec isn't triggering on the servers and i know that line is good as i've completed isolation testing on that command and manually triggered it

Note: Directories and Credentials remove to maintain privacy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appreciate the help ended up nutting it out and getting it to do what  want, the script is as follows:

```
$Servers = gc "C:\ServerList.txt"
Foreach ($Server in $Servers) 
    {
    [String]$cmd = "& cmd (C:\psexec.exe \\$Server -u Username -p Password cmd /c C:\Autolog.bat)"
    [ScriptBlock]$SB = [ScriptBlock]::Create($cmd)
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $SB -ArgumentList $Server
    echo "Started Script on $Server"
    }
```

I had to move some of the command out to a .bat because I don't have time to troubleshoot the issue but i'm essentially the C:\Autolog.bat contains "powershell.exe C:\Autolog.ps1" from the first script post

Answer (score 0):

This is likely way more complicated than it needs to be. I would run a scriptblock against that list of computers instead like so:

```
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("domain\username",(ConvertTo-SecureString 'password' -asplaintext -force))
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -ScriptBlock {. C:\Autolog.ps1} -Credential $cred
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Paul, Is this assuming that Powershell remote access is enabled? I forgot to mention that it isn't.
Also i'm not very fluent in powershell this is a learn as i go thing
Cheers 
Michael

Comment: You are correct, powershell remoting will need to be enabled.  Is there a particular reason it's not?  It is very quick and easy to set up; On the target server:
`Enable-PsRemoting -force` then 
`winrm quickconfig`

Comment: Because there are 1000 Server onsite here and I don't have authority to make the required changes unfortunately , trying to use PSEXEC though apparently the two have issues with each other

Answer (score 0):

Your job doesn't know what `$Server` means because jobs run in their own process, and so don't access the parent process' variables. You have to pass the argument. Try this:

`Start-Job -ScriptBlock $SB -ArgumentList $Server`